# Nonsparse SparseArray crashes the Kernel

Tags: bugs, kernel, sparse-arrays, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

On Windows 10, 64 bit, version 11.0.1, my kernel just started crashing for no reason as for as I can see. Does/should the following crash your kernel?

```
sparse = SparseArray[ArrayRules[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20] // N]];
Fold[Partition, sparse, {2, 5}]
```

It crashes only when the sparse array is all nonzero (nonsparse), and when the entries are not `_Integer`, and when the sparse array is created by rules. I use the workaround `Fold[Partition, Normal@sparse, {2, 5}]`, but I don't think `Normal` should need be there.

Comment: Crashes for me as well (same system configuration).

Comment: Crashed for me too (v11.0.1 on macOS Sierra).
Good way to reset the `In[]:=` numbers, though ;-)

Comment: It's definitely not `Fold`: doing `sp1 = Partition[sparse, 2];
Partition[sp1, 5]` crashes the kernel for me (Mac OSX 10.5, M V10.0.1), but `sp1 = Partition[sparse, 2] // Normal;
Partition[sp1, 5]` doesn't. So `Partition`ing the two-index `SparseArray` here is a problem.

Comment: But this works fine?! `mat = N@RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 2}]; 
Partition[SparseArray@mat, 5]`

Comment: @pmsoltani. You can programatically quit the kernel by evaluating `Quit[]` in a cell!

Comment: minimal example of issue.. `sparse = SparseArray[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.}];Fold[Partition, sparse, {2, 5}]`
`

Comment: Crashes 10.1.0 under Windows x64 as well.

Comment: reported it. It's the second partition that does it.

Comment: @march. yeah sure... just kidding ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the [just released](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/03/16/the-rd-pipeline-continues-launching-version-11-1/) Mathematica 11.1.

```
sparse = 
  SparseArray[ArrayRules[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20] // N]];
Fold[Partition, sparse, {2, 5}] // Head

(* SparseArray *)
```